# How to pass a variable into a the src of an iframe using Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, iframe

I'm building an app that suggests a random location to the user, and displays a google map on the page with that location.

The tutorial I'm following suggested using the iframe embed code to do this.

How can I take the variable created for the random location, 'barname', and pass that into the src url of the iframe?

Here is the code from the :

```
  <script>

            // Our List of Bars
            var bars = [
                'Siggys',
                'Blind Tiger',
                'Zum Schneider',
                'One Month',
                'Home Sweet Home',
                'Union Pool'
            ];

            // Our List of Friends
            var friends = [
                'Mattan',
                'Chris',
                'Lee',
                'Casey',
                'that girl you forgot to text back',
                'Kayne West',
                'Gerard'
            ];

            var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*bars.length);

            var barname = bars[randomNumber];

            var friendname = friends[randomNumber];

            document.write("How about you go to <strong>" + barname + "</strong> with <strong>" + friendname + "</strong>?");

        </script>
```

While I know there might be other ways to do this using the Google MAPS API for Javascript, I'm trying to figure out a simple solution using the iframe embed code, since that is what the tutorial suggested.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like GET parameter passing?

Here's what I tried: https://jsfiddle.net/4gb4p3sq/1/

```
  //Made an iframe in my html named locationFrame.

  //This takes locationFrame's src.
  var frameSrc = document.getElementById("locationFrame").src;

  //The src ends with a "?q=" which will be our GET parameter. 
  frameSrc = frameSrc + barname; 

  //example output: https://www.google.com/search??q=Siggys
  alert(frameSrc);

  //then add this function to your iframe to get the parameter
  function getParameterByName(name, url) {
      if (!url) {
        url = window.location.href;
      }
      name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
      var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
          results = regex.exec(url);
      if (!results) return null;
      if (!results[2]) return '';
      return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
  }

  //our GET parameter is called q and our src is stored at frameSrc
  var variableFromFirstHtml = getParameterByName('q', frameSrc);

  //alert to check if we're getting barname
  alert(variableFromFirstHtml);
})();
```